# Encrypt Integers in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, mcrypt

I've noticed that both openssl and mcrypt functions in PHP accept data to be encrypted as strings only. This means a value of (int)1234567890 is converted and encrypted as a 10-byte string when it was originally just a 4-byte int. Are there any encryption methods (bundled with PHP or as an external function/class) that allows for the encryption of integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If you want to encrypt your integer as the 4-byte binary representation, then you have to preconvert it:

```
$bin = pack("L", $int);    // unsigned 4-byte integer
xyz_crypt(...)
```

And [`unpack`](http://php.net/unpack) this again after decryption.

Answer (score 1):

mcrypt operates on strings, not integers, so you'll need to use [`pack()`](http://php.net/pack) to, well, pack an integer into a 4-byte string. (The inverse function is, sensibly enough, `unpack()`.)